# Preg Replace ID Number

Tags: php, regex, replace

I want to find `id="left-tabs( any digit )"` and replace it with `id="left-tabs99"`.

What am i doing wrong?

`preg_replace("/id='tabs-left(\d+)'/", "id='tabs-left99'", $form_start);`

Comment: `id="` is different from `id='` (double / single quote). Why are you processing HTML with regex? HTML parser building a DOM and XPath is more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
preg_replace("/id=\"tabs-left([0-9]+)\"/", "id='tabs-left99'", $form_start);
```

Comment: wow i feel stupid... i didnt even think about the single and double quotes. thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that you seem to look for single quotes in your expression, while you have double quotes in your string.